# How to get node line number in cheerio.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, cheerio

I am using `cheerio.js` as per below:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html,{withStartIndices : true});
```

When I use `console.log($('#element1'));`. It will return node with the character position.

```
   { 
     type: 'tag',
     name: 'h6',
     attribs: { align: 'center', id: 'r' },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     next: null,
     startIndex: 310,
.......
```

Is there any way to get the line number in `cheerio.js` for a specific element?

Comment: can you please tell me that In which version it (withStartIndices) works  becoz in latest version am not able to fetch line no because there is no option for allowing withStartIndices

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html, { withStartIndices: true });
const start = $('#element1').get(0).startIndex;
const lineNumber = html.substr(0, start).split('\n').length;
```

Comment: For me, I have to use `const $ = cheerio.load(html, { xmlMode: true, withStartIndices: true });`

Comment: can you please tell me that In which version it (withStartIndices) works  becoz in latest version am not able to fetch line no because there is no option for allowing withStartIndices